# how can use ActivityFragment in fragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I've the class:

`public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {`

and the method`

```
onNavigationDrawerItemSelected{.....
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, LoaderActivity.newInstance(position,name,userId)).commit();
```

The class `LoaderActivity` extends `Fragment`.

If I would like to change this:

The class `LoaderActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

how I can manage the  `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(....)` ???

Answer (score 0):

getSupportFragmentManager () is available in FragmentActivity.

For more details [FragmentActivity #getSupportFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())